Translating Spanish birth record into English
Can anybody translate or point me in the direction of where I can translate my great-grandfather’s Spanish birth record?
He was born in 1909 and I was sent over three photocopied pages of his birth record. I am desperately searching for help translating these so I can hopefully finally have a lead… I’ve been researching him for over 10-15 years, and this is the only thing I have found from before he immigrated to the USA.

Maybe if you included a scan of the record someone might help? I think I've made a stab at such things on this site.

See the FamilySearch Research Wiki articles Spanish Records Extraction Manual and Spain Genealogy for an overview of information in the Research Wiki that can be used to read and extract information from Spanish records.
The handwriting tutorials, genealogical word list, and other aids can be used in conjunction with tools like Google Translate if you want to try going through the record yourself.
If your language skills are rusty or minimal and you don't want to risk missing information by doing it yourself, there are various ways to get help:

Hire a professional by looking in directories like the member directory of the Association of Professional Genealogists.  See their article How to Hire a Professional Genealogist.
Find help via Cyndi's List: Spain & the Basque Country / España y El País Vasco » Professionals, Volunteers & Other Research Services
Ask for help in a FamilySearch Genealogy Research Group for Spain.
Look for a group about Spanish Genealogy on Facebook where members are willing to help with translations.

It can also help to review everything you know about your great-grandfather's life from records generated after he arrived in the USA,  for context and to gather clues.  The FamilySearch Research Wiki article Tracing Immigrants Search Strategies can alert you to information you might already have in the sources from the USA, which might be significant when you're translating the birth record.
